# Is it possible to display labels in background files (.imp) on Trimble GPS units?

Tags: gps, trimble

I have been trying to figure out if this is possible for a while now. I know if you load a file in as a data file, you can click on a feature and the label will pop up. However, you cannot view a data file if you are collecting data and creating a new data file. 
Has anyone had any success making labels show or know that it's not possible?

Comment: While you may get an answer here, you might also have better/faster luck over at http://surveyorconnect.com/ for this particular type of question.