# 1400 grids in a shapefile that I want grid labels to display in trimble

Tags: shapefile, labeling, gps, trimble, terrasync

So I have a grid boundary shapefile where I want to upload into TerraSync so I can collect data and know which grid I am currently in. Is there a way to do that in ArcMap or in TerraSync?

I found this article that is similar to what I am asking if my question is confusing to understand. [Is it possible to display labels in background files (.imp) on Trimble GPS units?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113422/is-it-possible-to-display-labels-in-background-files-imp-on-trimble-gps-units)

Comment: How could you use ArcMap to alter TerraSync? There seems a fundamental disconnect on what a shapefile contains here. To which labels are you referring? Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: what i am trying to do is bring a shapefile with 1400 grids into trimble as a guidance in the field. I want to show the grid labels so I can see what grid I am in as I walk.

Comment: You cannot turn on labels in TerraSync.  Better to use QField or ArcGIS Field Maps for this many polygons since the workaround (moving jpgs with world files onto the Trimble from ArcGIS) will be met with poor quality graphics and slow to render display qualities on the Trimble.

Comment: @GBG: could we possibly do it in pathfinder?